# Does one need to fill in a form for a Visa On Arrival?

Tags: paperwork, visas-on-arrival, indonesia

I am specifically looking for the case in Indonesia.

If a form is required, what sort of information is required on the form?

Or does this simply involve paying a fee and getting a stamp on my passport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a form to be filled, and that is the arrival card which you usually get it during the flight. The form has simple fields: Name, date of birth, passport information, address in Indonesia, duration of stay and flight number along with other usual stuff. No tricky or *smart* questions like in visa forms of other countries. This form should be handed to the immigration desk currently, not to the VOA desk like before.

### UPDATE (2016):

Earlier in 2016, no more landing cards and no more VOAs are required, except for business visas. All tourists who required a VOA before are now eligible to enter without landing cards or a printed VOA for 30 days, no more fees to be paid as well. The customs form is still required.

Comment: Are you referring to the arrival card? What other usual stuff? Is there a criminal check? :)

Comment: Yes, this is the arrival card.  It's very straightforward, with no tricky questions.  You can see a copy here: http://flights.indonesiamatters.com/files/2011/10/immigration-front.jpg

Comment: @deutschZuid the arrival card is what you need to get the VOA.

Answer (score 1):

It's no more than the standard arrivals form you need to fill out for most countries you'll visit.
And I've seen places where you had to fill out a lot more to get past customs even with a prearranged visa...

So yeah, there's kinda a form but it's nothing to fret about. Mostly if you have the cash (remember, cash only in US$, Euro, or UK Pounds at least when I arrived in Jakarta a few years ago) you get the stamp.